# How to initialize a parent class with a child object outside of the child's __init__ function

Tags: python

We have two basic class.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
        
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(self)
        A.__init__(self)
```

When initializing B, when can see that the "self" being passed to A is an instance of B object.

```
a = A()
b = B()

>> <__main__.B object at 0x0000021CC0E39700>
```

Now, if we print b, we can see that it is  also an instance of an instance of a B object. However, A cannot be initialized with an instance of B outside of B.

```
print(b)
A(b)

>> TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

And a here will be None:

```
b = B()
a = A.__init__(b)
```

How can that be done?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accompolish with this?  Are you meaning to run the parent's initialization code for the child class, or are you trying to create an instance of the parent class that has properties of the child class?  It's not clear what your goal is.

Comment: What is the objective here. A class has no need a child class to be initialized

Answer (score 0):

I think it can not be done.
The point here is, that upon calling the constructor of a class, python will create a new instance of that class in memory and then will hand this new object plus all the additional arguments to `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

So by calling `A(b)` you are actually calling an `__init__`-method, that has one additional parameter, i.e. `__init__(self, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `super` to do this

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ from A")
        self.a = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ from B")
        self.b = 2

b = B()
super(type(b), b).__init__()
print(b.a)
```

Output

```
__init__ from B
__init__ from A
1
```

Ideally you should handle all the parent class method calls inside the derived class methods.